# How to configure privileged access workstations in Azure?

Tags: azure

As a part of the Azure Security Benchmark, Privileged Access Workstation is recommended for Administration tasks - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/security-controls-v3-privileged-access#pa-6-use-privileged-access-workstations.

However, I don't any relevant documentation on setting up the privileged access workstations in Azure?

Comment: I only have knowledge of the functionally and the concept from an architectural point of view, but I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-devices) and [this other](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment) articles from the Microsoft documentation is what you are looking for. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privileged access workstations is used to protect identity, this is a Microsoft dedicated workstation.

1. Non-privileged workstations or Identity: - These computers are our local computers or VM’s used by users without administrator roles or Privileged identity roles. For example- If user wants to create and manage database in Azure VM. The user won’t have any administrator privileges or any other roles apart from just accessing VM and its database, these users fall under non-privileged. Also, user might require connecting to public internet to access data thus this computer cannot be used for privileged tasks.

Privileged workstation or Identity: - Now, as the administrator will have access to entire Azure Ad tenant and resources and require to perform privileged tasks like creating, deleting and assigning roles to users and groups, managing devices etc. You can connect your on-prem Privileged access workstation of any OS type whether Windows, MacOS, IpadOs, IOS, Linux, Chrome or your azure VM acting as a privileged identity workstation to Azure AD privileged identity management (PIM) solution. This will minimize the number of people who have access to secure information or resources, because that reduces the chance of

a malicious actor getting access

an authorized user inadvertently impacting a sensitive resource

What is Privileged Identity workstation: - Privileged identity workstation is a highly secured workstation which is hardened at hardware and software level to reduce the attack surface, As it contains sensitive data that can be managed only by privileged users. Example: - If you have a Active directory tenant with important GPO’s connected to your application running in production. You need to protect the Active directory installed in the windows server, by making that Windows server a privileged Identity workstation with very minimum access and hardened security so attackers or any non-privileged users cannot access the data inside it.

In Azure you can make use of PIM, here, you can have one on-prem local computer configured as Privileged identity workstation for your sensitive data or tasks or resources. And you can connect that device to Microsoft endpoint manager, Intune etc.

The main goal of using PAW in Azure, is to harden the PAW machines security at software, hardware and access level so the attack surface is reduced, and the PAW becomes highly secure. Imagine PAW as a machine which has your internal app data running which is important and secure data of your company, and you need to implement the highest security strategy to reduce any attack surface in this machine. This Paw can be your on prem machine or device having your company’s Active Directory or any internal apps. That is according to your goals.

I’ll walk you through some basic steps to enable the features according to this document here: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment

I have implemented Privileged access strategy for the

PAW.

1. Create Secure workstation users:- I have created 2 Users **Secure workstation User** and **Secure Workstation Administrator** and assigned them Intune Administrator role by visiting this link here :- https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109431 you can also create user and group directly from Azure Portal and assigned Intune administrator role to the Users.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. create four groups: **Secure Workstation Users**, **Secure Workstation Admins**, **Emergency Breakglass** and **Secure Workstation Devices**. I will create these groups in Azure Portal.

[image]

And added

**1)** **Created Secure Workstation Users group and added Secure Workstation User account, Secure Workstation user group and Secure Workstation Admin account to Secure Workstation Administrator group.**

Next steps on Privileged Access strategy: -

Now we will do Azure AD device configuration and connect our Device to Azure AD, in this example, I have used windows 10 machine. You can connect your on prem Windows 10 machine acting as a PAW to Azure AD, by following the steps here: - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/join-your-work-device-to-your-work-or-school-network-ef4d6adb-5095-4e51-829e-5457430f3973

For now, I have deployed one Windows 10 VM and enabled Azure AD login on the VM while creating. So that VM gets joined to Azure AD after deployment. This was done by Administrator account and no other user has the role to do it.

You can enroll your device on-prem Windows 10 machine by following the steps here: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/quickstart-enroll-windows-device

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My VM acting as a PAW machine is connected to Azure AD, thus we can manage this machine in Azure AD and Microsoft Intune.**

1. Specify who can join devices to Azure AD

[image]

2. Remove local admin rights and Require MFA for users to register or join device to Azure AD.

This method requires that users of the VIP, DevOps, and Privileged workstations have no administrator rights on their machines. Remove Local admin rights for the PAW.

[image]

3. Configure mobile device management

From the Azure portal: Browse to Azure Active Directory > Mobility (MDM and MAM) > Microsoft Intune. Change the MDM user scope setting to All. Select Save.

These steps allow you to manage any device with Microsoft Endpoint Manager. So we can manage our PAW machine from MDM with MS Intune.

[image]

4. Azure AD Conditional Access and Emergency account. Conditional Access only allowing secured workstation ability to access Azure portal Organizations should block Privileged Users from being able to connect to cloud management interfaces, portals and PowerShell, from non-PAW devices. Its necessary to have 2 Privileged Administrator account so even if 1 account gets locked we can use another account to access PAW.

Policy 1: All users with the directory role of Global Administrator, accessing the Microsoft Azure Management cloud app, and for Access controls, Grant access, but require multifactor authentication and require device to be marked as compliant.

[image]

Exclude emergency break glass group
[image]

[image]

[image]

And then create your conditional access policy for device compliance.

Create one more conditional access policy in Azure Portal by following the same settings as previous policy, just add these settings in addition: -

[image]

**SAW is Secured access workstation, which is your PAW machine, which can be on prem or on azure.**

5. Microsoft Intune configuration. Set enrollment restrictions preventing BYOD

[image]

6. Create an Autopilot deployment profile

[image]

Select Next –

[image]

[image]

Select Next and Create

[image]

7. Enrollment Status Page

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click Next and Create enrolment Profile for your PAW.

8. Configure Windows Update

[image]

[image]

[image]

Click Next and Create> Update ring is created for your Windows 10 PAW device: -

[image]

9. Microsoft Defender for Endpoint Intune integration

You can get the Microsoft defender for endpoint Free trial for your account from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/security/business/endpoint-security/microsoft-defender-endpoint

And enable advanced connection for Microsoft Intune and connect your Windows PAW Machine.

10. Create the device configuration profile to onboard Windows devices

[image]

Click Create

[image]

To onboard the file > Refer the steps here –

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-endpoints-sccm?view=o365-worldwide

Add secure workstation user group in assignments and click Create.

11. All the steps above were done to harden the Software and secure your PAW’s from attack surface on software and access level. Now, To harden your PAW on Hardware level download the script from here and run it in your local PAW machine joined to Azure AD or PAW VM running on cloud –

To successfully complete the hardening of the solution, download and execute the appropriate script. Find the download links for your desired **profile level**:

**Profile**

**Download location**

**Filename**

Enterprise

https://aka.ms/securedworkstationgit

Enterprise-Workstation-Windows10-(20H2).ps1

Specialized

https://aka.ms/securedworkstationgit

Specialized - Windows10-(20H2).ps1

Privileged

https://aka.ms/securedworkstationgit

Privileged-Windows10-(20H2).ps1

This script will update and create policies for you, after this script runs successfully, Assign this policies to your secure workstation device group. You can also run the Intune data export script `DeviceConfiguration_Export.ps1` from the [DeviceConfiguration GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/DeviceConfiguration) to export all current Intune profiles for comparison, and evaluation of the profiles.

12. Create Windows Firewall rules- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-windows-firewall-rules-in-intune

[image]

Click Create

Select the profile > In Basic tab add name and description as Windows Defender Firewall> Now, you can configure Microsoft Defender Firewall settings according to your goals of security –

[image]

[image]

I have blocked file transfer and tried to give exemption to ICMP protocol. You can add additional network rules as per your security goals for your PAW.

Assign this rule to Secure Workstation admin and emergency glass group.

You can also add URL proxy for your privileged access strategy set up.

Remove local applications from your PAW machine and only keep your critical business or internal apps for management of PAW and the sensitive data inside.

You can add Visual studio code in your machine to connect to apps or Azure apps, via GitHub or DevOps. If you require any app in your PAW, you can make use of Intune manage company portal to push apps in your PAW, refer here: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/store-apps-company-portal-app

In your Microsoft Defender security center, after taking Microsoft Security center Free Trial or purchasing license you can add these settings additionally.

Enable Defender for Cloud Apps and connect to Defender ATP to block access the risky URLs:

- In [Microsoft Defender Security Center](https://securitycenter.windows.com/) > Settings > Advanced features, set Microsoft Defender for Cloud Apps integration > **ON**
- In [Microsoft Defender Security Center](https://securitycenter.windows.com/) > Settings > Advanced features, set Custom network indicators > **ON**
- In [Microsoft Defender for Cloud Apps portal](https://portal.cloudappsecurity.com/) > Settings > Microsoft Defender ATP integration > Select **Block unsanctioned apps**

13)Follow these steps inside your PAW to install custom applications and assign settings. By installing  VS code inside the PAW :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment#deploy-applications-using-intune

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment#upload-vs-code-to-microsoft-endpoint-manager

At-last use PowerShell and run this script in your PAW machine- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment#use-powershell-to-create-custom-apps-and-settings

After this step validate and test your device by initiating the PowerShell script, Refer here :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment#validate-and-test-your-deployment-with-your-first-device

Use the same csv generated in the above step to import devices into Autopilot :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/compass/privileged-access-deployment#import-devices-into-autopilot

Assign this device to your Secure workstation administrator groups.

You can make use of MS defender endpoint to monitor the health and security of your PAW and use Application insights and query to get additional insights.